# Running Oracle SQL query over several dates

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports

Within Crystal Reports, I'm using the following query (against an Oracle database) to generate data for a single field in a report:

```
SELECT SUM(e1.ENT_LOCAL_AMOUNT+e1.ENT_DISCRETIONARY_AMOUNT) AS "Entitlement"
FROM CLAIM_PERIODS cp1
JOIN ENTITLEMENTS e1
  ON cp1.CPE_REFNO=e1.ENT_CPE_REFNO
WHERE e1.ENT_REFNO=(SELECT MAX(to_number(e2.ENT_REFNO)) 
  FROM ENTITLEMENTS e2
  WHERE e1.ENT_CPE_REFNO=e2.ENT_CPE_REFNO
  AND (e2.ENT_START_DATE <= {?HB_As_At_Date} 
  AND e2.ENT_END_DATE > {?HB_As_At_Date})
  AND e2.ENT_CREATED_DATE<={?HB_As_At_Date})
  AND cp1.CPE_CPA_CPY_CODE='HB'
```

This works fine and returns a single integer value, based on the {?HB_As_At_Date} supplied (The {?} syntax is Crystal's way of embedding parameter values into SQL).  The content of the above query isn't my issue though - what I want to do is run it repeatedly for several different dates, and have that output be what gets fed through to Crystal for use in the report.

So say I want this query run for every Monday in September, I'd currently run the Crystal report once with a parameter of 07/09/2015, then again for 14/09/2015, etc.

I'd instead like to use my SELECT statement in conjunction with a query that tabulates this as needed - running the above once each per date required.  With the output being something like:

```
Date        Entitlement
07/09/2015  450,000.00
14/09/2015  460,123.00
21/09/2015  465,456.00
28/09/2015  468,789.00
```

Could someone point me in the right direction in terms of which keywords I should be reading up on here?  I'd imagine it's quite straight-forward to generate a set of dates and run my SQL as a subquery using them, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: The only way I can think of is creating a stored procedure (SP). You will have to decide the maximum number of dates that you may use, let's say 5, and pass them as parameters to the SP. Inside the SP, you check the parameters one by one to see if they have a value or NULL. Run the query once for each parameter that has a value and return the results.

Comment: Thanks very much for this reply.  I don't have access to create a stored procedure on the database, but will see if this can be arranged.  I would have thought there's a neater way to do it too - will keep investigating.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. I also try to avoid stored procedures whenever I can. If you really want to do it in a query, there is an ugly way to do it. You will have to repeat your query for each date parameter and then combine those sub-queries using `UNION`. Would you like me to post that as an answer?

Comment: Ah yes - that might actually be the best way for me to go - just copy/paste the same query over and over and UNION them all together, changing the date on each.  Thank you for the offer of that answer - I should be okay from here.  Although feel free if that's the only way I can upvote you. :)  Wish there was a way I could just supply start/end parameters and have the rest done for me, but maybe I can write a script elsewhere to generate the SQL using UNIONS.

Comment: OK, I posted an answer for you which also addresses your comment about using a script to generate the SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of without using a stored procedure is by repeating (i.e. copy/paste) your query for each date parameter and then combining them as sub-queries using UNION. Something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(e1.ENT_LOCAL_AMOUNT+e1.ENT_DISCRETIONARY_AMOUNT) AS "Entitlement"
FROM CLAIM_PERIODS cp1
JOIN ENTITLEMENTS e1
  ON cp1.CPE_REFNO=e1.ENT_CPE_REFNO
WHERE e1.ENT_REFNO=(SELECT MAX(to_number(e2.ENT_REFNO)) 
  FROM ENTITLEMENTS e2
  WHERE e1.ENT_CPE_REFNO=e2.ENT_CPE_REFNO
  AND (e2.ENT_START_DATE <= {?HB_As_At_Date_1} 
  AND e2.ENT_END_DATE > {?HB_As_At_Date_1})
  AND e2.ENT_CREATED_DATE<={?HB_As_At_Date_1})
  AND cp1.CPE_CPA_CPY_CODE='HB'

UNION

SELECT SUM(e1.ENT_LOCAL_AMOUNT+e1.ENT_DISCRETIONARY_AMOUNT) AS "Entitlement"
FROM CLAIM_PERIODS cp1
JOIN ENTITLEMENTS e1
  ON cp1.CPE_REFNO=e1.ENT_CPE_REFNO
WHERE e1.ENT_REFNO=(SELECT MAX(to_number(e2.ENT_REFNO)) 
  FROM ENTITLEMENTS e2
  WHERE e1.ENT_CPE_REFNO=e2.ENT_CPE_REFNO
  AND (e2.ENT_START_DATE <= {?HB_As_At_Date_2} 
  AND e2.ENT_END_DATE > {?HB_As_At_Date_2})
  AND e2.ENT_CREATED_DATE<={?HB_As_At_Date_2})
  AND cp1.CPE_CPA_CPY_CODE='HB'
```

As for your comment about writing a script for that, I don't know how you are running your report. But if you have an app/website running it, then you can generate the SQL in the app/website's language and assign it to the report object before you run it. Or even better, you can generate the SQL, run it, and assign the results to the report object. I do this all the time as I prefer my code to run the queries rather than the report itself, because I follow the layered design pattern in my app. The report will be located in the presentation layer which cannot communicate with the database directly, instead it calls the business/data layer with generates/runs the query and returns the results to the business/presentation layer.

Comment: Thanks very much Racil.  That makes sense, and probably the best I can hope for for now - unless I uncover anything else in my investigations. I'll look into some way to generate the SQL - should be simple enough.  Apologies - I can't publicly upvote your answer yet as I'm new to the site, but have marked it as the most helpful here.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the parameter to take the input as multiple values and change the query as

Use either start or end but not both

```
SELECT SUM(e1.ENT_LOCAL_AMOUNT+e1.ENT_DISCRETIONARY_AMOUNT) AS "Entitlement"
FROM CLAIM_PERIODS cp1
JOIN ENTITLEMENTS e1
  ON cp1.CPE_REFNO=e1.ENT_CPE_REFNO
WHERE e1.ENT_REFNO=(SELECT MAX(to_number(e2.ENT_REFNO)) 
  FROM ENTITLEMENTS e2
  WHERE e1.ENT_CPE_REFNO=e2.ENT_CPE_REFNO
  AND e2.ENT_END_DATE in ( {?HB_As_At_Date})
  AND e2.ENT_CREATED_DATE in ({?HB_As_At_Date})
  AND cp1.CPE_CPA_CPY_CODE='HB'
```

Comment: Thanks.  This will still involve manually picking each date required - although that's an improvement on doing the same thing when rerunning the report over and over.  Will give it a try.  I'll need to alter the query a little more, as the ENT_CREATED_DATE could be any value as long as it's less than or equal to the parameter supplied.  So won't necessarily be exactly equal to the date supplied.    Likewise ENT_START_DATE and ENT_END_DATE.  But I see what you mean with the multiple values - thanks - an improvement on the current situation even if not quite what I was hoping to achieve. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a more elegant way to solve this problem.
Let's suppose that the main query is t1 , and the parameters to use are available in a table t2.

Here is an example, where the the sub-queries t1 and t2 can be replaced by real tables.

```
select t1.title , t2.ref_date, t2.dt_label
from (
    select 'abc' title from dual union all
    select 'def' title from dual
    ) t1
cross join
(
    select to_date('01.07.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy') ref_date,'S1/2019' dt_label  from dual union all
    select to_date('01.12.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy') ref_date,'Y/2019' dt_label  from dual union all
    select to_date('01.07.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy') ref_date,'S1/2020' dt_label  from dual union all
    select to_date('01.12.2020','dd.mm.yyyy') ref_date, 'Y/2020' dt_label from dual
) t2
where t2.ref_date < to_date('01.08.2020','dd.mm.yyyy')
order by t2.ref_date, t1.title;
```

This way, the query remain the same, while the extraction parameters are filled in an auxiliary table.